# Programmatically connecting to wifi network doesn't allow outside communication

Tags: android, android-10.0

I'm building an Android application that during onboarding flow needs to connect to a wifi network. I'm able to connect to the SSID successfully but when I attempt to go to the browser i'm not able to load any webpages even though the Wifi settings saying it's connected via my application.

Is there a way to specify in Android the ability to use that wifi network outside of my app? The reason is this is crucial is we're using an Android MDM to manage devices remotely.

```
class WifiActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val callback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
            super.onAvailable(network)

            Timber.d("NETWORK! Network is available $network. Binding to network")
            connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network)

            Timber.d("NETWORK! Connected to SSID ${wifiManager.connectionInfo.ssid}")
        }

        override fun onUnavailable() {
            super.onUnavailable()

            Timber.d("NETWORK! Network is unavailable")
        }

        override fun onLost(network: Network) {
            super.onLost(network)

            Timber.d("NETWORK! Network is lost $network")
        }

        override fun onLosing(network: Network, maxMsToLive: Int) {
            super.onLosing(network, maxMsToLive)

            Timber.d("NETWORK! Network is losing $network")
        }
    }

    private val suggestionCallback = object: BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            if (!intent?.action.equals(WifiManager.ACTION_WIFI_NETWORK_SUGGESTION_POST_CONNECTION)) {
                Timber.d("NETWORK! Broadcast was not WIFI_NETWORK_SUGGESTION_POST_CONNECTION")
                return
            }

            Timber.d("NETWORK! I think we're on wifi now?")
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Timber.d("NETWORK! Registering default network callback")
        connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(callback)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wifi)

        connect.setOnClickListener {
            Timber.d("NETWORK! Going to attempt connect. ${ssid.text.toString()}")
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                Timber.d("NETWORK! SDK and OS requirements satisfied")
                val wifiBuilder = WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                wifiBuilder.setSsid(ssid.text.toString())
                wifiBuilder.setWpa2Passphrase(password.text.toString())
                val networkSpecifier = wifiBuilder.build()
                Timber.d("NETWORK! WifiNetworkSpecifier $networkSpecifier")

                val networkBuilder = NetworkRequest.Builder()
                networkBuilder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                networkBuilder.setNetworkSpecifier(networkSpecifier)
                val networkRequest = networkBuilder.build()
                Timber.d("NETWORK! NetworkRequest $networkRequest")


                Timber.d("NETWORK! Will request network")
                connectivityManager.requestNetwork(networkRequest, callback)

                // Wifi Suggestion
                val suggestion = WifiNetworkSuggestion
                    .Builder()
                    .setSsid(ssid.text.toString())
                    .setWpa2Passphrase(password.text.toString())
                    .build()

                val suggestions = listOf(suggestion)
                val status = wifiManager.addNetworkSuggestions(suggestions)

                if (status != WifiManager.STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_SUCCESS) {
                    Timber.d("NETWORK! Failed to add suggestion $suggestion")
                } else {
                    Timber.d("NETWORK! Successfully added a suggestion of $suggestion")
                }

                val intentFilter = IntentFilter(WifiManager.ACTION_WIFI_NETWORK_SUGGESTION_POST_CONNECTION)
                applicationContext.registerReceiver(suggestionCallback, intentFilter)
            } else {
                Timber.d("NETWORK! Cant connect to a wifi on this device programatically")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The call `connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network)` can only bind your app to a specific network or network type. You can not influence the connectivity of other apps.
This is only up to the android OS and the behavior, whether a mobile connection and wifi work at the same, is very inconsistent across manufacturers.

Comment: So is there another way to configure a wifi connection from an app for the entire Android system?